# How to use a document to search for keywords in file names

Tags: excel, bash, macos

I have an Excel document with 1,200 rows of numbers in Column A. I'd like to use this document to search a server full of hundreds of thousands of images, with Bash on Mac OSX, looking for any instance of these numbers in the file names and output those file names to another document. I'd like to also specify to only look for files with the .png extension.

I'm having trouble writing this script. The part that is eluding me is how to use the Excel document to search each row. I can write code that looks for one row at a time, but how can I call upon the Excel doc to search for all the rows at once?

Comment: It's unclear how you interface with excel. Do you mean .csv perhaps? For people to understand you, show us 1) an example of excel row, and 2) examples of files it should result in finding. You say _I can write code that looks for one row at a time_, show this code also, so people understand what you're doing.

Comment: Could you give an example of code you've written so far to accomplish this?

Comment: If you have it working for one *number*, then export the column to a CSV, read each line, use the value read as your *number*, done

Comment: Lose all the Excel stuff. Instead, export the first column as a CSV and show your code. Hopefully you have full access to the server locally through its filesystem and you don't have to access it via HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

you should put the whole column into a text file and run a while loop.
which will the read the lines (e.g while IFS=$'\t' read k v ; do )  of the file and grep that string in to the ls command (e.g. ls | grep $str).